# Seaborn Heatmap Colorbar Tick Label

Tags: python-3.x, seaborn

I have numbers that currently like this:

12.5

6.7

2

and I want them to show up on a color bar like this:

$12.5K

$6.7K

$2K

using this approach:

```
from matplotlib.ticker import FuncFormatter
def function(x, pos=0):
#What do I put here???
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(FuncFormatter(function))
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to return your `x` values formatted in your chosen way. For your example, you could do this:

```
def DollarFunc(x,pos=0):
    return "\${}K".format(x)

ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(FuncFormatter(DollarFunc))
```